# Create pdf from html file and adjust "print" size

Tags: power-automate

I' working with power automate cloud flow.

Im having trouble adjusting the final pdf content size and can't find a solution which is really workable.
The scenario is quite simple - create table like view which as around 9 columns with html -> dynamically add data in that table with variables-> create html file in onedrive -> convert file to pdf in onedrive -> create pdf file in onedrive.

Now, the original html data for that table which i converted to html. The created html file (from flow) looks perfect and as expected. Everything works and looks nice.
The pdf is created succesfully and in general the flow works. However, somewhere between creating the html file and the final pdf, i apparently have to tell the flow how wide and high to "print" the content into the pdf.

Right now it looks as if you print a website and the width is too wide / half the screen is cut off on the final pdf...

any ideas?
I cant  use API PDF convertors actions due to company policies. I'm using convert file action which is capturing data only upto two columns which fits in a A4 size pdf anything above 2 columns added in the html code doesn't get captured in the pdf and it comes as empty. but the html file captures everything perfectly.

Seems to me in general my problem is not unusual, but maybe someone has a good work around?

thanks!

I tried manually writing the html code and adjusting the width and height of the html table. I also tried to create a similar table in an outlook email and fetch the email body as html in the power automate flow. But it gives the same problem, and the html content just doesn't fit in the A4 size pdf as it has 9 columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this issue by adding the scale and viewport size within the html file. Kindly try the below HTML code in your header section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Can you please try with this media type in html file.
<style media="print">or
<style media="screen">